# How to recall a CSS animation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im creating a slideview with a couple of Images and Im trying to apply a CSS animation to all of the images.

```
<script>
    function slideImages(){
          var img = document.getElementById('picShow');
          var images = ['images/img2.jpg','images/img3.jpg','images/img4.jpg'];
          var x = 0;
          function slide(){
               if (x < images.length){
                   x=x+1;
               }else{
                   x=1;
               }
               img.innerHTML = "<img src="+images[x-1]+">";
           }
           setInterval(slide,2500);
     }
</script>
```

```
#picShow{
    animation:fade 1.5s linear;
}
@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div id="picShow">
      <img src="images/img1.jpg" id = "img">
</div>
<script>slideImages();</script>
```

I expect all images to be animated but only the first image gets animated. Can any one help with this please..

Comment: use array.map with that slide function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the animation on the containing `<div id="picShow">` the animation is actually on the whole show div, not the individual images.  Actually, the fact that you are changing out the image source using javascript will impact that as well, since as far as the CSS knows, you just have one  element that happens to have a new attribute (as opposed to a new  element).

Aside from the JS, though, CSS animations will only run once unless you specify how many times you want it to run.  If you want it too loop you could try:

```
#picShow {
  /* set delay to match JS timing and iteration count to infinite: */
  animation:fade 1.5s linear 2.5s infinite; 
}
```

Most likely though, you will run into issues with JS and CSS not starting their 2.5 second timers at the same time.

A more consistent way to do this would be to use CSS transitions instead of annimations, and use JS to toggle a class name on the image that's active instead of toggling the src attribute:

HTML:

```
<div id="picShow">
  <img id="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/09f234" class="active" />
  <img id="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"  />
  <img id="img3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/09f/fff" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#picShow img {
  transition: opacity 1.5s linear;
  opacity: .0;
  position:absolute;
}
#picShow img.active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Your JS will need to be modified to remove the class `active` and add it to the next image. Adding/removing the class will cause the CSS transition to fire each time.  I did a quick jQuery version that uses some of your original logic in this codepen to illustrate...nothing there that would be hard to do with vanilla JS if you prefer:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OGJLwO

Comment: I used your advice and adjusted the CSS to work for the image, then changed `img.innerHTML = "<img src="+images[x-1]+">";` to `img.innerHTML = "<img src="+images[x-1]+" id='active'>";`  now its working. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working! If my answer helped you arrive at your solution, it would be awesome if you'd upvote or accept it as the answer! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `img.innerHTML = "<img src="+images[x-1]+">"` won't work with CSS animations.

There are two ways to approach this.

The first is to use classes and apply CSS animations to them.

```js
function slideImages() {
  var picShow = document.getElementById("picShow");
  
  picShow.children[picShow.dataset.activeSlide].classList.remove("active")
  
  picShow.dataset.activeSlide = (parseInt(picShow.dataset.activeSlide) + 1) % picShow.children.length
  
  picShow.children[picShow.dataset.activeSlide].classList.add("active")
}
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {opacity: 1} 
    to {opacity: 0}
}

#picShow{
  height: 320px;
}
#picShow img{
  position: absolute;
}
#picShow img.active{
    animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
    opacity: 1;
}
#picShow img:not(.active){
    animation: fadeOut 1s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="picShow" data-active-slide="0">
  <img class="active" src="https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image">
  <img src="https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-2.jpg/image">
</div>
<button onclick="slideImages()">Next Image</button>
```

Here I made a very simple example. If the images are in the same position and only one has the `active` class, you can use JavaScript to change the image by changing which `<img>` element has the `active` class.

The second way is to use Web Animations API. Read [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API) if you're interested.